# htaccess with square brackets

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi everyone, I have a serious problem with my `.htaccess` file.
The issue is that it does not seem to allow square brackets in the URL.

I have these 2 lines:

`RewriteRule ^mp3/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ index.php?dir=$1.`

`RewriteRule ^mp3/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ index.php?dir=$1/$2 [L]`

This should allow me to have a URL like:
http://veqhite.info/mp3/mp3/Mp3-Shqip-2012/dffds.html

Where `Mp3-Shqip-2012` and `dffds` are seperate directories.
But when I have an URL with square brackets [] like this:
`http://veqhite.info/mp3/mp3/Mp3-Shqip-2012/meda-shqip-[2012].html`

I receive a not found page `The requested URL /mp3/mp3/Mp3-Shqip-2012/meda-shqip-[2012].html was not found on this server.`

I think I should modify the `.htaccess` rewrite rule to allow that but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^mp3/([A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]]+).html$ index.php?dir=$1.

RewriteRule ^mp3/([A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\[\]]+).html$ index.php?dir=$1/$2 [L]
```

Hope this will help